# Counting permutations of a multiset restricted by nearness condition

Tags: combinatorics

I've been scratching the noggin on this for a bit, and have come up blank so far.
Given a multiset $S$ with $Z$ zeros and $O$ ones, how many permutations are there where there is at least one pair of ones separated by at most $N$ zeros?

E.g., with $S=\{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0\}$ and $N=2$, $\{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1\}$ matches the restriction, but $\{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1\}$ does not.

I've looked at the enumeration of smaller cases, searching for a pattern to the counts (some tantalizingly close OEIS hits), but no luck so far.

Any ideas/pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total number of permutations, $P$ = $Z+O\choose Z$.{select the positions for Z Zeroes, positions of One's will get automatically fixed}.

Let $X$ denote the permutaion where all One's are separated by at-least $N+1$ Zeroes. Required answer is $P-X$.

Let $x_i$ denote the number of Zeroes between $i$-th and $i+1$-th $1$, $1\le i\le O-1$. And $x_0$ define number of zeroes before the first one and $x_O  $ denote the number of zeroes after the last one. Then by [multinomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) theorem, $X$ is the number of solutions to the following equation,

$$\sum_{i=0}^O x_i = Z , \ x_0\ge 0,x_O\ge 0 \text{ and  remaining } x_i \ge N+1. $$
$$\implies \sum_{i=0}^O x_i = Z-(O-1)(N+1) , \ x_i \ge 0$$

Thus, $X = {Z-((O-1)(N+1)) + O+1 -1 \choose (O+1-1)}$.

Comment: Thanks arindam - seems close, but not quite, e.g., with Z=O=6 and N=2, the final result for X results in 28, but obviously there are no cases where three or more zeros separate all pairs of ones in any partition of that case. Studying your derivation - I'm hoping a typo... thanks again.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. For Z=O=6 and N=2, P = $12 \choose 6$ and X = $-3 \choose 6$ = 0 so the answer is P-X = P.

Comment: Ah, face-desk moment - I've been doing much lately with extended binomial coeffs. with negative values, was in that mode of (not) thinking. Doh! - Thanks again, +1 and accept.

Comment: yah.. i guessed that. :)